# Compiler Construction - Why does some tokens requires a final state with a backtrack?

Tags: compiler-construction, lexical-analysis, dfa

So i'm studying compiler construction for an exam , but there seems something i can't understand.

Let's assume the following set of terminals:

```
T = {:, *, =, (, ), <, >, {, }, [a..z], [0..9]}
```

And the set of accepted tokens (`l` points to a letter , and `d` points to a digit):

```
A = { l(l|d)* , (d)+ , { (anything)* } , : , := , < , <= , <> , > , >= , ( , (* , * , *) }
```

Here's the state transition diagram:

[image: State transition diargram]

Now i understand that state number **20** needs backtracking because:

- A `(` might come , but it might be followed by a `*` .
- A `:` might come , but it might be followed by a `=` .
- A `<` might come , but it might be followed by a `=` or `>` .
- A `>` might come , but it might be followed by a `=` .

But what about states **3** , **5** , and **11** ? , why do we need to backtrack them ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like "backtracking" here means you've read a character, but you haven't consumed it. So for state 3 we've consumed a `l` and maybe some `l` and `d`, and then we get some character that is neither; that character terminates the `l(l|d)*` rule, but then still needs to be processed.

Contrast that with state 7 where we read a `}` character to terminate the rule, and we've used up the `}` so we don't need to "backtrack."

This explanation is consistent with states 3, 5, and 20, but I don't get why 11 needs to backtrack.